# Setup Cloud VPN tunnel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vpn

I have some question about setup VPN tunnel between Cloud VPN and on-premises internal network.

In GCP side, I have a flex app engine application running on my custom VPC and would like to connect to the device that sitting on-premises internal network.

To my understanding, the Cloud VPN with VPN tunnel should work. but I have no idea what kind of hardware I need to build the on-premises VPN gateway, so it can communicate with the app engine through the Cloud VPN.

The on-premises internal network is access public internet through its own router provided from the ISP.

Any hardware recommendations or ways to make sure it works with Cloud VPN? or any experiences with a similar case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish an App Engine app reaching into an on-premise network by establishing a VPN.

The simplest solution is to create a VPN network between the on-premise network and the projects' VPC network where the app engine flex is located.

Now, answering your question about the HW, that you can use for VPN establishment, let me share public Google documentation about some vendors, that you can use for VPN to GCP:

With Classic VPN, your on-premises hosts communicate through one or more IPsec VPN tunnels to Compute Engine Virtual Machine (VM) instances in your project's VPC networks.

Interop-guides[https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/interop-guides]
classic-topologies for[https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/classic-topologies]

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks Agustin, looks like those HW is not cheap and can't use those firewall appliances in US$100 - US$200 range that selling on Amazon.